# Why typeof NULL is return undefined?

Tags: javascript, typeof

> Why `typeof NULL` is return `undefined`  while  `typeof null` return `object` ?

Check this snippet

```js
console.log(typeof NULL)// undefined 

console.log(typeof null)// object
```

Comment: isn't that because js is case-sensitive? https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596000480/ch02s02.html

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript is case-sensitive, so they are two different things:

`NULL` is a variable, which is not defined.

`null` is the null-object.

Answer (score 6):

> JavaScript is a case-sensitive language. This means that language keywords, variables, function names, and any other identifiers must always be typed with a consistent capitalization of letters. The while keyword, for example, must be typed “while”, not “While” or “WHILE”. Similarly, online, Online, OnLine, and ONLINE are four distinct variable names.

So `NULL` is a variable that you have not defined yet, whereas `null` is

> The value null represents the intentional absence of any object value.

To read more:

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596000480/ch02s02.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

Answer (score 1):

NULL and null do not reppresent the same thing, since it is case sensitive.

Check here the reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null